# Semimartingale decomposition and filtrations

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-calculus, martingales

In short: I am trying to understand how the decomposition of a semimartingale into its local martingale and finite variation components depends on the filtration we are using.

So, taking a toy example, let’s say I have a process $X$ that is solution to the following SDE:

$dX_t = (\mu + Y_t) dt + dW_t,$

$dY_t = \sigma dZ_t$,

$d\langle W,Z\rangle_t = \rho dt,$

where $W$ and $Z$ are Brownian motions.

Over the filtration generated by $W$ and $Z$, the semimartingale decomposition of $X$ can be read off from the SDE. It explicitely depends on $Z$ and $W$.

Since I cannot recover the two Brownian motions from observations of $X$ alone, I expect the filtration generated by $X$ to be different from the one generated by $W$ and $Z$.

My first question: is it possible to write down the semimartingale decomposition of $X$ over its natural filtration?

The only angle of attack I have in mind is to approximate the diffusion by a discrete time Markov chain, use the explicit formula given by the Doob decomposition for discrete time processes, then hope that a weak convergence argument lets me conclude in the end. That seems far from elegant.

That leads to my second question: is there any general result on the topic?

Comment: This is sort of the reverse of the topic of enlargements of filtrations. In fact, when you consider subfiltrations, it is not even clear that $X$ remains a semimartingale or even adapted. It is thus not clear what the Doob-Meyer decomposition would mean. Of course, you can always take conditional expectations.

Comment: @S.Surace Thanks for your comment. Stricker’s theorem states that if you take a semimartingale X according to some filtration F and if G is a subfiltration of F for which X is adapted, then X is a G-semimartingale. In my case, F is generated by W and Z, while G is generated by X.

Comment: That's right, I was looking at it more generally. Your case is actually what is considered in filtering theory, with $Y_t$ being the signal and $X_t$ the observation at time $t$, with white correlated signal and observation noise, and observation function $h(x)=\mu+x$. For $\rho=0$ it is a standard result that the so-called innovation process $X_t-\int_0^t\hat h_sds$ is $\mathcal{F}^X_t$-adapted Brownian motion. The correlated noise case is treated in some of the books on nonlinear filtering theory.

Comment: In the uncorrelated case, the Doob-Meyer decomposition can thus be obtained by taking conditional expectation of the finite variation part, giving the innovation process as a martingale part. I don't remember what happens in the correlated noise case.

Comment: By $\hat h_s$, I denote $E[h(Y_s)|\mathcal{F}^X_s]$.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Example 5.2 in: T. R. Bielecki, J. Jakubowski, M. Jeanblanc, M. Niewęgłowski, *Semimartingales and Shrinkage of Filtration*, [arXiv:1803.03700](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.03700), applies here.